# Can I plot random points on a chart.js or Google Charts chart?

Tags: google-visualization, chart.js

I'm creating a chart representing centile curves in a child's development.

So from 1 to 18 years old, you take the caculated BMI and plot it, and see if you're in a healthy/overweight/underweight range.

I've mocked up the 98th and 50th centile lines in a chart.js chart:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

var data = {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"],
    datasets: [
                {
            label: "98th",
            fillColor: "rgba(254,162,116,1)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [20.88534167, 19.81059732, 19.21573931, 18.79199228, 18.69458621, 18.94370352, 19.468687, 20.19907676, 21.0399018, 21.92476198, 22.81691772, 23.69887299, 24.57539594, 25.43122437, 26.24504753, 26.99794153, 27.67845403, 28.28680281]
        },
        {
            label: "50th",
            fillColor: "rgba(92,195,105,1)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [17.644, 16.655, 16.133, 15.752, 15.547, 15.498, 15.564, 15.748, 16.037, 16.423, 16.892, 17.433, 18.037, 18.675, 19.317, 19.938, 20.519, 21.052]
        }
    ]
};

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, { 
    pointDot: false
});
```

[(as you can see here)](http://jsfiddle.net/9xo9m5x3/2/)

So now I've got the different regions (let's say anything in green is "normal" range, anything in red is overweight), I want to plot some actual weights.

So at 2 years, you plot 15.3. At 3 years you plot 16.5, etc.

I don't really need a line chart to visualise these plots, although that would be acceptable if it's the only way of doing it.

Ideally, I just want to put "X" marks on the chart where the measurements actually are.

I guess what I want is a scatter chart overlayed onto these line charts.

Like this:
[image: What I'm trying to achieve - plotted points on a chart]

You can do this with Flot which is what's currently being used, but there are some separate issues whereby we're trying to migrate to either chart.js or Google Charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your scatter points will come within the area that you have already drawn you can do this in the onAnimationComplete callback

```
var scatterPoints = [
    { x: 2, y: 15 },
    { x: 5.5, y: 20 }
]

var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    pointDot: false,
    // disable tooltips so that a redraw won't wipe out our scatter points
    // alternatively we could extend the chart and move the scatter point drawing into the draw override
    showTooltips: false,
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        var self = this;
        var ctx = self.chart.ctx;

        // style
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";

        scatterPoints.forEach(function (scatterPoint) {
            ctx.fillText("x",
                // adjust x axis value if the x axis does not start at 0

                self.scale.calculateX(scatterPoint.x - Number(self.scale.xLabels[0])),
                self.scale.calculateY(scatterPoint.y));
        })
    }
});
```

If you are only going to have integral values for x (i.e. ones that are already labels) you can do it in a simpler way - be adding a third series with the line color set to transparent.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sucfguw1/

---

[image]

Comment: Sweet! Thank you! I'm not always going to have integral values for x, I usually won't (it'll be pure chance if I do). Your scatter approach is good, I like it. I'm going to have a look at your second option to extend the chart and move the drawing into the draw override so I can have tooltips. Do you know if I can have tooltips only for the scatter points? The curves are more for reference, but I do need tooltips for the scatter points. Thanks again

Comment: @bgs264 - I'm pretty sure you can have tooltips for the scatter points (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984226 on how to add a new tooltip) too but you'll also have to take care of adding a hover area so that the tooltips show up when you hover over / near the points (haven't tried it myself yet though). Cheers!

Comment: @bgs264 - forgot that there's also a scatter plot community extension (check out the Chart.js docs > Community Extensions section) that support scatter plots. Give a holler here / or add a question if that won't work for you and you are stuck on the tooltips.